# Split string using delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to split the string using the delimiter '|'. But, I want to get '|' from my sample data in the second example. How can I achieve this?

```
f() {
  local IFS='|'
  local foo
  set -f # Disable glob expansion
  foo=( $@ ) # Deliberately unquoted
  set +f
  printf '%d\n' "${#foo[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
}

f 'un|dodecaedro|per|||tirare|per|i danni'
```

Expected output:

```
un
dodecaedro
per
|
tirare
per
i danni
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: un
    dodecaedro
    per
|
tirare
per
i danni

Comment: @Morton: I have updated expected output. Thank you.

Comment: Is the first line of expected output really "undo"? If so what's the rule to create that? Also, how can you decide if `|||` is a single field `|||` containing a `|` or 2 separate fields with nothing in them, `||` and `||`?

Comment: @Morton: I have updated the expected output now. It should be un and dodecaedro. `|||` is a single field with a `|` between delimiters `||`. I need `|` in the output. Also, I appreciate for any alternate solutions for this.

Comment: I understand that's what you want output for that case, but until you can state WHY that's the output you want, you/we can't write a program to produce it. Let's say your input was `a||b`. Presumably you'd want 3 fields `a NULL b` output with the 2nd field being the null string. Now with `a|||b` why should that be treated as 3 fields `a | b` instead of 4 fields `a NULL NULL b`? What if you had input of `a||||b` - is that 5 fields or 4 or something else? It'd help if you provided a few lines of input and expected output with those kind of edge/educational cases instead of just 1 line.

Comment: In my script, I am defining array elements related to files like filename, extension, directory, file size, field terminator inside the file, number of fields defined inside data of text field ect. During this case, most of the times field delimiter is ';', however sometimes '|' is defined and my program is failing.

Comment: None of that background info matters. Just update your question to tell us the rule for how to determine when an `|` should be considered to be inside a field vs a field separator and provide sample input/output as I suggested demonstrating that rule. Right now you're in danger of getting a solution that looks like it'd work but is far more complicated than it has to be and/or will only work for the specific sample you posted and won't work for other input samples.

Comment: I agree with you Morton. There is lot of ambiguity to determine the fields vs field separator. However, I don't have any clue about it. sorry.

Comment: You can't write a program without knowing what you want the program to do so.... Good luck :-)! I don't mean to sound facetious, there's just really nothing more to be said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some good way to produce what you expected, here is my approach, I hope you are using recent version of bash and here string is supported

```
string='un|dodecaedro|per|||tirare|per|i danni'

awk '{
    n=split($0,A,"|")
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(length(A[i]) == 0 && length(A[i+1])==0)
        {
            print "|"; i+=1
        }
        else
        {
            print A[i]
        }
    }
     }'  <<<"$string"
```

**Resulting**

```
 $ bash f
 un
 dodecaedro
 per
 |
 tirare
 per
 i danni
```

Answer (score 1):

Crude way to get this output from awk:

```
s='un|dodecaedro|per|||tirare|per|i danni'
awk '{p=$0; while ((n=index(p, "|"))) { m=(n==1)?n:n-1; print substr(p, 1, m);
      p=substr(p, n+1)}; print p }' <<< "$s"
un
dodecaedro
per
|
|
tirare
per
i danni
```

Comment: I have seen that but would one know in `|||` which one is delimiter and which one is literal pipe?

Comment: So far you don't which is why I haven't tried to post a solution yet since so far we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I just posted it so that OP can get close to what the desired output is. However ambiguity still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `sed` to simply replace two consecutive newlines (that result from `set`'s parsing and output with `\n` as the separator) with `\n|` after the fact (but @Ed Morton's caveat re ambiguity applies):

```
f() {
  local IFS='|'
  local foo
  set -f # Disable glob expansion
  foo=( $@ ) # Deliberately unquoted
  set +f
  printf '%d\n' "${#foo[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}" | sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n\n/\n|/g'
}

f 'un|dodecaedro|per|||tirare|per|i danni'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how a "real" CSV parser handles that data:

```
echo 'un|dodecaedro|per|||tirare|per|i danni' | 
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.parse_line($_, :col_sep=>"|").join("\n")'
```

```
un
dodecaedro
per


tirare
per
i danni
```

What if we were to use quotes on the "troublesome" field:

```
echo 'un|dodecaedro|per|"|"|tirare|per|i danni' |
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.parse_line($_, :col_sep=>"|").join("\n")'
```

```
un
dodecaedro
per
|
tirare
per
i danni
```

So, you have to ensure your data is in a clean state **first**.